# Members on EE Core

Tags: members, core

Has anyone tried to implement basic membership system within the Core version of Expressionengine. Basicly, I need login / logout functions to be executed within the frontend.

As I understand Solspace User provides such functionality for EE Core users, but, is it possible to implement such features without paying for EE license / buying expensive addons (such as Solspace Member).

Thanks!

Comment: the core module looks like something i could for my expressionengine website, is it available on ee3?

Comment: Hi @Lloyd_07 are you referring to the 1st party (native) EE Member module? If so, it's not available on the free version of EE. See https://store.ellislab.com/#ee-core

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any add-ons that I know of that would add front-end member functionality to the Core version of ExpressionEngine. Solspace User, as well as Zoo Visitor and Profile:Edit all build on top of EE's existing member module, and therefore don't work on EE Core.

I do have to ask though, what kind of project are you working on where EE's price tag makes it  too expensive? With the amount of work EE saves in building custom functionality, I've never come across a project where the price of EE would eclipse that of adding on to something free.

Comment: Like, a small card club, or hobby-group where you made a basic website for. And then want to put some information in member-only templates? Or put some information between ```{if logged_in}``` tags.

Comment: That's precisely what the "feature-limited" Core version is limited by. Unfortunately EE is probably not the tool to use if you need member features and don't have the budget for the commercial license. Unfortunate as it may be, it's just a fact of life.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a small website with EE-core for a non-profit theater-group and also needed some basic member login / logout functionality to allow members to login and see members-only templates and members-only `{if logged_in}` content. Members can be added and edited via the control panel by an admin.

You can try-out a mashup i made of an older version of the freemember plugin,  for use in EE-core.
(yes it's beta) via this Gist:

**Core_member**
https://gist.github.com/GDmac/6829953

Comment: I guess it really comes down to how much of your time do you want to put into this in order to save $300. At my hourly rate that comes down to just a few hours before it costs more to hack something together than just cough up the money.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words. Always great to be able to also support the small communities.

Comment: I'm doing a PoC for authentication and it looks like this extension will be just what I need to start off -w/o having to put out the $300 to see if what I'm thinking will work. Good job, @GDmac

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in a previously deleted question, all of the free member management solutions (and indeed, all of the commercial ones too) build on top of EE's integrated member management functions. Therefore it's not possible to add member management to EE core, without a *lot* of work re-implementing all this functionality.

That said, you'd be crazy not to spend the $299 and save yourself a lot of work. Plus you're supporting EllisLab and the continued development and support of ExpressionEngine :)